# android getThoroughfare as writable string?

Tags: java, android, location-based-service

I am currently creating an app which uses location based variables and for arguments sake, I want to take in the string which is assigned from `getThoroughfare()` and afaik, it's a String according to the API but lets say I do this

```
class Game extends MapActivity{

public random function(){
if(addresses!= null){
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    this.locationText.append("\n" + address.getThoroughfare() + ", " + address.getLocality());  
        userLoc = address.getThoroughfare();
        System.out.println(userLoc);
        }
}
```

This works and will print out the name of the Street but within another class, if I check it like

```
if(Game.userLoc == myStreetString){
//do stuff
}
```

it will not work, let I have insured the strings matched, what gives? Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of == for comparing strings.

```
if(Game.userLoc.equals(myStreetString)){
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, my sloppy coding. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

try to use the following code

```
if(Game.userLoc.contains(myStreetString)){
```

for next time please read the API documentation for Address on [address Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)